# How to make the custom module effect on the node and only one content type?

Tags: 7

The following code is used to output five images, according to what's number contained in `$fen`. I want to put the button in nodes of a specific content type (e.g. "company").
Which code should I use in my module to get this?

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="submit" name="fen" />
</form>
<?php
  $star = getStar($_GET['fen']);        
  echo "<img src=\"xing_$xin.jpg\" />";

  function getStar($fen) {
    if ($fen < 10) {
        return 1;
    }
    elseif ($fen < 100) {
      return 2;
    }
    elseif ($fen < 1000) {
      return 3;
    }
    elseif ($fen < 10000) {
      return 4;
    }
    else {
      return 5;
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: A module doesn't output a form field, if not using the [form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/group/form_api/6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add content to nodes, you can in drupal 6 use the `hook_nodeapi` where `op` is `view`.

As you get the node object, you can detect the node type ect. You would need to add something like this to your module

```
module_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch($op) {
    case 'view':
      if ($node->type == 'node_type') {
        // $a3 indicates if teaser
        // $a4 indicates if page
        $node->content['my_additional_field'] = array(
          '#value' => 'HTML', // create html with theme or form function. 
          '#weight' => 10,
        );
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: how to use $a3 and $a4 ? and could you make an simple example for me. add an text box to the editor then he can enter the text and then shows it under node article.when view the node

Comment: @enjoylife: It's not that hard: `$a3` is `TRUE` if the node is displayed as a teaser and `$a4` is `TRUE` if the node is displayed as full page.

Comment: See [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) at api.drupal.org - also see the nodeapi_example in the [Examples project](http://drupal.org/project/examples)